# HTML5 support in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, html

Is HTML5 support in Visual Studio 10 partial or full? I mean intellisense and validation are fine, but will ASP.NET controls emit HTML5 compliant output as well?

ASP.NET menu control  as an example. Will its contents be rendered as HTML5  element or it will emit traditional  style output?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that the current lot of ASP.NET controls work correctly without requiring HTML5 support, it seems very unlikely that they will emit "HTML5".